# Angular $http.get: How to catch all the errors?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-promise, angular-http

Im sending a form to nodejs for authentication. Using `$http.get` in the following function and adding a `promise` > `.then`. In production, does this handle all the errors that I may get from the server? Do I need to add anything else to this function?

```
MyApp.controller("Login", function($scope, $http){

    $scope.checkuser = function(user){

        $http.get('/login', user).then(function(response){

            if(response.data){
                console.log(response.data);
                    //based on response.data create if else .. 
            } else {
                console.log("nothing returned");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

As always, many thanks!

Comment: It doesn't handle non successful responses (200). If 500, 401, etc. then callback will not fire. Add catch block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function only handles successful server responses like 200, but it doesn't account for server exceptions 500 or authorized errors 401, etc. For those you need to provide catch callback:

```
$http.get('/login', user)
.then(function(response) {

    if (response.data) {
        console.log(response.data);
        //based on response.data create if else .. 
    } else {
        console.log("nothing returned");
    }
})
.catch(function() {
    // handle error
    console.log('error occurred');
})
```

Comment: So in the `catch`, I still need to do `if(response.data=="401"){ do this}`  or `if(response.data=="500"){ do this}` ?

Comment: In `catch` do `if(response.status=="401"){ do this};  if(response.status=="500"){ do something else};` See [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - General Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage)

Answer (score 2):

I would add the second callback to your `.then`, which is the error handler.

```
MyApp.controller("Login", function($scope, $http){

  $scope.checkuser = function(user){

    $http.get('/login', user).then(function(response){

        if(response.data){
            console.log(response.data);
                //based on response.data create if else .. 
        } else {
            console.log("nothing returned");
        }
    }, function(error){
        //THIS IS YOUR ERROR HANDLER. DO ERROR THINGS IN HERE!
    });
  }
});
```