# Angular $http.get() - how to catch "access control" errors

Tags: angularjs, error-handling, cors

I'm using $http.get() to commit an API request which works just fine as long as I enable CORS in my browser while testing.  Of course, that's just a bandaid.

I found this article:
[Angular $http.get: How to catch all the errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988661/angular-http-get-how-to-catch-all-the-errors)

And have my code set up with a then().catch() and while the catch code is executed as expected, the error is still thrown:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'url here' due to access control checks.

Even when I manually disable CORS for development's sake, I still get 401 errors, despite my catch().

The goal is prevent the old "red text" errors in the console and just handle them with an alert to the user.

Comment: Most browser dev tools report bad AJAX responses regardless of whether you handle them.  There is nothing you can do about that.

Comment: you need to enable cors in your api

Answer (score 0):

When you send an http request in a browser, it first sends `OPTIONS` request which is called preflight. The browser blocks the request if the response for the preflight request doesn't contain `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers.

This preflight request is transparent to Javascript. So, for every ajax call, the browser sends two requests if the destination is cross-domain.

Even though you catch the error, browser is going to report the network error in the console if the preflight request fails.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Avoid browser registering network error in the console?